# snowflake snowsql Error 250003 (n/a): Failed to execute request: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='https Failed to establish a new connection

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

encountering Error while try to connect using CMD (Admin)

250003 (n/a): Failed to execute request: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='https Failed to establish a new connection.
Snowflake account is on Azure.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you post the example of how are you trying to connect using SnowSQL? The error alone is not enough to understand where the issue is.

Comment: on command Prompt >snowsql -a https://XXXX.west-us-2.azure.snowflakecomputing.com/ -u username Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment, the problem is when using the account option:

```
>snowsql -a XXXX.west-us-2.azure.snowflakecomputing.com -u username
```

The account should not include this part **.snowflakecomputing.com**, so your call should be:

```
>snowsql -a XXXX.west-us-2.azure -u username
```

Comment: Thank you Sergiu.  You saved me from giving up on this issue for the day.  Had already wasted a long time trying other suggestions, but you were the only one that cleared it up

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue while giving the hostname as https://xxxxxxxx.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com, then I removed **https://**. It connected successfully.